# Retrofit - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit

I am trying to parse my own JSON, but getting `JSONSyntaxException`, here is how my **JSON** looks:

```
{
    "type":"success",
    "value":[
        {
            "id":1,
            "title":"Title - 1",
         "name":{
            "first":"First - 1",
            "last":"Last - 1"
         },
            "hobbies":[
                "Writing Code - 1",
            "Listening Music - 1"
            ]
        },
       .....
    ]
}
```

**Log says:**

```
E/app.retrofit_chucknorries.MainActivity$2: ERROR: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT 
at line 7 column 12 path $.value[0].name
01-21 12:41:52.156 28936-28936/app.retrofit_chucknorries 
W/System.err: retrofit.RetrofitError: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT 
at line 7 column 12 path $.value[0].name
```

Where I am doing `mistake ?` I just made few small modifications as per my `requirement and classes` else everything almost same as in original code
**Value.java:**

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Value {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;

    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    private String title;

    @SerializedName("hobbies")
    @Expose
    private List<String> hobbies = new ArrayList<String>();

    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private List<Name> name = new ArrayList<Name>();

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<Name> getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(List<Name> name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<String> getHobbies() {
        return hobbies;
    }

    public void setHobbies(List<String> hobbies) {
        this.hobbies = hobbies;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your Master.java class, your name is not an array!

```
private List<Name> name = new ArrayList<Name>();
```

Change to this instead and try:

```
 private Name name;
```

Actually by seeing the logs of the exception you can tell this.

Comment: The log says: "BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT 
at line 7", as your line 7 of your Json should be this line:  "name":{

Comment: yeah thank you I did mistake. I ticked as useful and will accept in 5 mins, Can I ask a question ?

Comment: check an updated screenshot above, I want to know How Can I get Hobbies and Name from JSON.....

Comment: To get name: `for(Value value : values) {String name = value.getName()}`

Comment: but I am using two different - different textviews for first name and last name, please check above screen.

Comment: Like `firstNameTV.setText(value.getName().getFirst())`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101257/discussion-between-oreo-and-jiyeh).