# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT in retrofit 2

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I try to get all data using parameter in GET method retrofit 2.x
but respon is Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT in retrofit 2

this is my code to access URL service

```
public interface BukuResepMasakanAPI {
public static String baseURL = "http://10.108.233.76/buku_resep_masakan_service/";

//membuat Instance Retrofit
Retrofit client = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(baseURL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();


@POST("jenis_resep")
public Call<JenisResepModel> getJenisResep(@Body JenisResepModel model);

@GET("get_resep_by_jenis/{id_jenis_resep}")
public Call<List<DetailResepModel>> getDetailResep(@Path("id_jenis_resep") String id_jenis_resep);
```

}

and this is my code to call retrofit

```
public void loadData(){
    BukuResepMasakanAPI apiService = BukuResepMasakanAPI.client.create(BukuResepMasakanAPI.class);
    DetailResepModel model = new DetailResepModel();
    Log.d("lappet",""+idJenisResep);
    Call<List<DetailResepModel>> call = apiService.getDetailResep(idJenisResep);

    //proses call
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<DetailResepModel>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<DetailResepModel>> call, Response<List<DetailResepModel>> response) {
            List<DetailResepModel> resep = response.body();
            Log.d("idjenisresep",""+idJenisResep+" size "+resep.size());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<DetailResepModel>> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Failed to connect",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("failed", "" + t.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

i hope you can help me to solve that problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrofit - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN\_ARRAY but was BEGIN\_OBJECT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34917713/retrofit-java-lang-illegalstateexception-expected-begin-array-but-was-begin-o)

Answer (score 0):

Your error is saying it received a single JSON object, but your Callback expected a list.

(I assume this is the method the error refers to)

```
@GET("get_resep_by_jenis/{id_jenis_resep}")
public Call<List<DetailResepModel>>
```

You should try changing that to

```
@GET("get_resep_by_jenis/{id_jenis_resep}")
public Call<DetailResepModel>
```

Comment: when I try like you recommended it will be return size of object = 0, but I have data to get.

Comment: That sounds better than the error message you were getting, but I can't help with that